# Access Forms: Fix the options in a ComboBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a form were there are several ComboBox, I have to get it to be edited, erase nor substitute any of the shown records.

I've tried to add this property in the form load:

```
Me!Tipo.LimitToList = True
```

Even that way, It's possible to erase the selected option in the ComboBox. Can't explain this. How to create a ComboBox in a form seriously, where the user only can choose what it's already there without erasing or modifying it?
rio serio donde el usuario sólo puede elegir lo que hay y no puede borrarlo?

Comment: `.AllowValueListEdits=False`  Not sure i get what you are after though :)

Comment: What should happen when the user selects an entry in the combo box - what purpose does the entry in the combo box serve? Is this combobox linked to a table? A table for data entry or a look-up table?

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak Spanish so I hope I'm not missing an important information about your question.

The `LimitToList` property which you have already found yourself prevents the user from choosing a value which is not already in the list. So whenever a user edits or delets a value so that the resulting value is different to all elements of the list, the choice will not be accepted and the user will be informed about this by a message box. So what you already have done is that a user can not choose an invalid value.

However, this does not prevent the user from actually trying to input an invalid value. He is still able to edit or delete the value he sees at the moment. You could accomplish this by only allow the usage of predefined keys like missinglinq pointed out [here](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=128280#10)

> Private Sub ComboBoxName_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
>
> Select Case KeyCode
>
> Case vbKeyReturn, vbKeyTab, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown
>          KeyCode = KeyCode  'Accept these keys
>
> Case Else
>          KeyCode = 0 'Block all other keys    End Select
>
> End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the combo to only be editable on a new record you will need to add some code to the forms Current Event

```
Me.cmbYourCombo.Locked = Not Me.NewRecord
```

This will lock the combo from editing on anything but a new record.